# Adding some text below the video popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I want to add some text below the my video popup, like the example picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiiOW.png]

How can I do that?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items:[
            {
                src: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_I70TYm9qQ',
                type:'iframe'
            },
        ],
        type: 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default caption works only with image type.

To make it work with `iframe` type, you'll need to add element that will hold title to [iframe markup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe_type) and parse it in markupParse callback, e.g.:

```
callbacks: {
  markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
   values.title = item.el.attr('title'); // will use title attribute of target DOM element
  }
}
```

Here is example http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/zjtbr

Comment: thanks for answer but I can't get it to how to use it with "open" function. $('.video').magnificPopup.open is that possible to use it that way? Cause I want to show them with page load. not click on something to open it.